# Reopen - Is it legal for a company to demand you show up 15 minutes before a shift to “prepare” but not pay you for this time?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

I believe that [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52271/is-it-legal-for-a-company-to-demand-you-show-up-15-minutes-before-a-shift-to-pr) should be reopened as it is both useful and on-topic. I've suggested an edit which should push it in the reopen queue.

Arguments:

- Questions asking for general advice within a legal context have been judged as being on-topic. The crucial criteria seems to be that:

  - this site's audience and/or HR managers could be expected to know the answer
  - it's asking about a general guideline rather than an interpretation of case law (the answer to the latter should always be "consult a lawyer")
- This question has a broadly applicable answer
- Questions like this are likely to come up again in future (it's one of the more popular question varieties to pop up on workplace-related Q&A sites)
- [A very similar question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/do-i-have-to-get-to-the-office-any-earlier-than-my-start-time) is one of the more popular on this site and has remained open, presumably because it doesn't explicitly mention a legal angle (not a duplicate as it concerns the UK)

Comment: "It also needs some cleanup work and propably a retitle but I'll leave that for if/when it's reopened" -- actually, it's best to make whatever changes are needed to prepare it for reopening.  And as a bonus, an edit will send the question into the reopen review queue.  So if you see something that can help a question on its path to reopening, please don't wait -- go ahead and fix it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah I forgot to update this. I have in fact [already made the edit.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/33166) Regarding Alec's Reject Vote: there's a lot of red and green in there but the author's intent should not have changed: he clarified a few things in the comments which I incorporated in his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've voted to re-open. The edit improved the post significantly, and I agree that it looks pretty good now.

Comment: The question is reopened now.

Comment: And [answered](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/52303/25739), thanks for the reopen. I think I covered the FLSA well but it'd be interesting to get input from anyone with HR experience.